# C++ pure virtual function call ... Some pattern for this situation?

Tags: c++-cx

I found this problem. In the folowing code I am unable to create object **Mother**, I get **"R6025 - pure virtual function call**" error. When class **Parent** is not abstract, everythig is OK. Is there some pattern to have class **Parent** abstract and not get this error ?

```
    ref class Parent;
    ref class Child
    {
    internal:
        Child(Parent^ r)
        {
            parent = WeakReference(r); // ERROR R6025 - pure virtual function call
        }
    private:
        WeakReference parent;
    };

    ref class Parent abstract
    {
    internal:
        Parent()
        {
            child = ref new Child(this);
        }

        Child^ child;

        virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    };
    ref class Mother : Parent
    {
    internal:
        Mother() :
            Parent()
        {
        }

        virtual void DoSomething()  override
        {
        }
    };
```

Comment: I don't recognise this as C++. However if parent is abstract, you cannot possibly instantiate an object which has a "WeakReference parent;" as one of its fields.

Comment: It is C++/CX, I am converting C# code to this language. C# does not have problems with this pattern... And I thing it is useful.

Comment: In C#, and if WeakReference is a reference type, "WeakReference parent;" means "a reference to a WeakReference". In C++, "WeakReference parent;" means "an _actual_ instance of a WeakReference  object". The latter cannot happen if it is an abstract type. I don't know C++/CX, but _if_ Parent^ r denotes "a reference to a Parent", then maybe "WeakReference  ^ parent" will compile, as it would denote a _reference_ to a WeakReference - not an actual object.

Comment: Do keep in mind that any resemblance to C# or C++/CLI is purely coincidental.  You are programming native C++ here.  And you are dealing with a C++ rule, an object is not fully constructed until *after* its constructor finishes running.  Before that happens, none of its virtual methods behave virtual.  You can't easily see the one that's virtual, it is the IUnknown::QueryInterface() method.   You'll have to byte the bullet and add a SetChild() method.